# how to display a bar chart (jqplot) when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

i try to display a bar chart on a pressing on a button but without success , can some one can give me an example ? ( i'm new in java script)
i try that:

```
$("#vm_buttons").button();
        $("#vm_buttons").click(function (evt) {
            // increment the value of output
          //  alert ('click');
            bar_chart_add('test_1',[1,3,4],[2,5,6] ,"test",['a','b','c']);

        });
```

bar_chart is function that make  bar chart .

10x, 
perry

Comment: Hello please check the [mcve] as the barchat code could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your button an ID. Then, use the click(function()) to achieve the functionality. I used jqplot in the example -

See this - 
https://jsfiddle.net/ha3y1omd/

```
<button type="button" id="btnclick" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

<div class="container" id="chart1">
</div>
```

In your JS file,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnclick').click(function(){
       CapacityChart();
    });
  });

function CapacityChart()    {
       var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
}
```

Comment: 10x , it work if i only have one button if i try 2 like her : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ha3y1omd/1/
 it doesn't  work i want that to plot will switch between 1 plot to another.
10x for the help
perry

Comment: Did you mean you want to have 2 buttons and upon clicking each button, a graph to be displayed in the same position/div?

Comment: Hi, i want that the graph will be displayed in the same position/div not one after another. 
10x for the help! 
Perry

Comment: I have updated the code and here it is https://jsfiddle.net/ha3y1omd/4/   If this answers your question, please mark this as the answer.